# jQuery Mobile click handling .click

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm new to jQuery and jQuery mobile.  I'm trying to understand how to execute a function when a button is clicked.  I've tried the methods I've seen in tutorials, but it isn't working for me. Here's my code. I get the 'document is ready' alert, but don't get an alert when the button is clicked.  I've also tried it with the .click() outside of the ready function.  If anyone can find what I'm doing wrong, it will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>test</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.js">        </script>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('document is ready');

    $('#testButton').click(function() {
        alert('testButton has been clicked');       
        });
    }); 


        </script>


    </head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page" id="home">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Test</h1>
        </div>

    <div data-role="content">

    <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="#testButton">Test Button</a>

    </div>
</div>  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the # from the id value in your a tag. # is a jQuery selecter which species its an ID. Change this line

```
     <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="#testButton">Test Button</a>
```

TO:

```
    <a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="testButton">Test Button</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="#testButton">Test Button</a>
```

with:

```
<a href="#" data-role="button" class="ui-btn ui-corner-all" id="testButton">Test Button</a>
```

The id shouldn't have the "#".